# ECMAscript random syntax error

Tags: javascript, list, button, random

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
<!-- Begin
function go_to(Random link) {
window.location=Random link;
}
function rand_link() {
var a;
a = 1+Math.round(Math.random()*2);   // a = random number between 1-3
if (a==m1) go_to("Cape Fear");
if (a==m2) go_to("The Good, the Bad and the Ugly");
if (a==m3) go_to("The Omen");
}
// End -->
</SCRIPT>

<BODY>

<FORM NAME="myForm">
<SELECT NAME="mylist" onChange="disp_text()">
<OPTION VALUE="m1">Cape Fear
<OPTION VALUE="m2">The Good, the Bad and the Ugly
<OPTION VALUE="m3">The Omen
<OPTION VALUE="m4">The Godfather
<OPTION VALUE="m5">Forrest Gump
</SELECT>
<INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="myButton" VALUE="Random link"
onClick="rand_link()">
</FORM>
</body>
```

i would like to random

```
<OPTION VALUE="m1">Cape Fear
<OPTION VALUE="m2">The Good, the Bad and the Ugly
<OPTION VALUE="m3">The Omen
<OPTION VALUE="m4">The Godfather
<OPTION VALUE="m5">Forrest Gump
```

above syntax how can i correct my code?
my question is how to random list by button @_@ . i have tried to edit a couple of time :(

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow! Please edit your question; adding the following points may get you better answers: 1. What are you trying to accomplish ("random list by button" - order? select? remove? something else?)? 2. What have you tried so far? 3. What results did you get? 4. How did that differ from the results you were expecting? (please be more specific, these are not self-evident from the current state of your question)

Answer (score 1):

I fixed some of the code for you.  Since you didn't have any urls to redirect to, I just used alert you can fix it later.

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
<!--
function go_to(Random_link) {
  alert(Random_link);
}

function rand_link() {
  var a= "m"+(1+Math.round(Math.random()*2));   // a = random number between 1-3
  if (a == "m1"){ 
    go_to("Cape Fear");
  } else if (a == "m2") {
    go_to("The Good, the Bad and the Ugly");
  } else if (a == "m3"){ 
    go_to("The Omen");
  }
}
// End -->
</SCRIPT>

<BODY>

<FORM NAME="myForm">
  <SELECT NAME="mylist" onChange="disp_text()">
    <OPTION VALUE="m1">Cape Fear</option>
    <OPTION VALUE="m2">The Good, the Bad and the Ugly</option>
    <OPTION VALUE="m3">The Omen</option>
    <OPTION VALUE="m4">The Godfather</option>
    <OPTION VALUE="m5">Forrest Gump</option>
  </SELECT>
  <INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="myButton" VALUE="Random link" onClick="rand_link()">
</FORM>
</body>
```

As you can see you weren't commenting out "Begin" in your orignal text.  You also were not closing the options in your select drop down.  You were comparing a, an integer 1, 2, or 3.  with an undefined variable m1, m2 and m3, instead of the string "m1", "m2", or "m3".  I also changed to if else, a cannot be both "m3" as well as "m2" or "m1".
I could've provided a better answer if as the original comment says you were more specific with your question.

Comment: While you are at it, you should remove the commenting out (`<!--` ... `-->`) and the `language` attribute.

Comment: yo answer is function only aleart :P         <br> i want to function on the list (<OPTION VALUE="m1">Cape Fear</option>
    <OPTION VALUE="m2">The Good, the Bad and the Ugly</option>
    <OPTION VALUE="m3">The Omen</option>
    <OPTION VALUE="m4">The Godfather</option>
    <OPTION VALUE="m5">Forrest Gump</option>) /*<SELECT>
  </SELECT> must be working, i dont need alert bonus  */

Comment: I have no clue what you're trying to say.

Comment: i want to random drop down list

Comment: You want to create a drop down list that is in a random order?

Comment: yes      /* i am awful sorry my human language is toooooooooo  bad :P */